# Adding Hovertext on KendoUI Grid Column Headers

Tags: css, kendo-ui

I'm trying to add custom hovertext (like a tooltip), to the column headers in a KendoUI grid. The text should be specific to each column and ideally not displayed on anything but the header row. There isn't a tooltip option for the Grid object but I'm not sure if there might be a way to do it either using CSS or their [row template](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/rowtemplate.html) configuration.

Would be interested in hearing if anyone has done this before and if so how, or if it may not be possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the contents of the tooltip is static, then you could use the [columns.headerTemplate](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.headerTemplate) to then add a [tooltip](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/tooltip/index.html) to the header.

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rally25rs/eJRTn/2/).

The code:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    OrderID: {
                        type: "number"
                    },
                    Freight: {
                        type: "number"
                    },
                    ShipName: {
                        type: "string"
                    },
                    OrderDate: {
                        type: "date"
                    },
                    ShipCity: {
                        type: "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 20,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true
    },
    height: 430,
    filterable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,
    columns: [{
        field: "OrderID",
        filterable: false
    },
        "Freight", {
        field: "OrderDate",
        title: "Order Date",
        width: 120,
        format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
        headerTemplate: '<span title="This is the date the order was made.">Order Date</span>'
    }, {
        field: "ShipName",
        title: "Ship Name",
        width: 260,
        headerTemplate: '<span title="The company the order was shipped to.">Ship Name</span>'
    }, {
        field: "ShipCity",
        title: "Ship City",
        width: 150,
        headerTemplate: '<span title="The city the order was shipped to.">Ship City</span>'
    }]
});

$("#grid").kendoTooltip({
    filter: ".k-header span"
});
```

Comment: a little enhancement: filter: ".k-header .k-link span" targets the header cell more accurately. The one in answer makes filter popup to not show sometimes because of the tooltip coming in between.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to define tooltip on every columnn header, you can define [kendoTooltip](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tooltip/index) on grid thead element like this:

```
grid.thead.kendoTooltip({
    filter: "th",
    content: function (e) {
        var target = e.target;
        return $(target).text();
    }
});
```

This shows hover text when you hover the header anywhere, not only on text in the header. The tooltip is shown even when the column has minimal width and the text of the header is not presented/shown in its full length or isn't shown at all. See [example](http://jsbin.com/kenigotiki/1/edit?html,js,output).

---

Here's the complete code from the example at jsbin.com, in case it needs to be reproduced in the future:

**HTML:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="grid"></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    OrderID: {
                        type: "number"
                    },
                    Freight: {
                        type: "number"
                    },
                    ShipName: {
                        type: "string"
                    },
                    OrderDate: {
                        type: "date"
                    },
                    ShipCity: {
                        type: "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 20,
        serverPaging: true
    },
    height: 430,

    columns: [{
            field: "OrderID",
            width: 250
        }, {
            field: "ShipName",
            title: "Ship Name",
            width: 200

        }
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");

grid.thead.kendoTooltip({
    filter: "th",
    content: function (e) {
        var target = e.target; // element for which the tooltip is shown
        return $(target).text();
    }
});
```

Comment: Links can be helpful as supplemental information, but [link-only answers are strongly discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/228805). Please include a summary of the linked information that's relevant to the question, and explain how it resolves the issue.

Comment: Better, but you should always provide the complete code needed to reproduce examples from sites like jsbin and jsfiddle, in case of link rot. Definitely do post the significant part in its own separate block, as you did; then add the rest of the code for reference at the bottom. I've added it for you. And +1 since you've shown that this works.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone attempting to do this with Kendo UI MVC it can be achieved by using the following logic:

On the grids `DataBound` event create a `JavaScript` function to handle the databound.

Within that `JavaScript` function add the following code (for my example I've named my function `createToolTip()`

```
function createToolTip() {

    $("tr > th").kendoTooltip({
        position: "top"
    });
}
```

This will create a tool tip to display on the grids header with the position of the tool tip above the header.