# Kendo Grid Column Title

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, grid

How can I have html inside kendo grid column title?

I want to display a popover in the title

I dont see a way to add html in the title of kendo-grid-column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Hovertext on KendoUI Grid Column Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645587/adding-hovertext-on-kendoui-grid-column-headers)

Comment: Thats right, @G_P, [`column.headerTemplate`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.headertemplate) is the answer.